# reportlab: ValueError: Invalid color value '<css function: moz-linear-gradient(left, #ef6059, #fffd6c)>'

Tags: python, css, reportlab

I am trying to generate pdf from html using xhtml2pdf when running against my html file the script exit on the following lines:

```
return toColor(value, default) # Calling the reportlab function
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/colors.py", line 850, in __call__
    raise ValueError('Invalid color value %r' % arg)
ValueError: Invalid color value '<css function: moz-linear-gradient(left, #ef6059, #fffd6c)>'
```

any idea ?

Comment: `-moz-linear-gradient` not `moz-linear-gradient`

Comment: in the html it appears with -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #EF6059,  #FFFD6C)